# Automating update.php after git pulls

Tags: 7, version-control

So I have the following infrastructure (that cannot be changed):

- A central repository
- A ton of drupal websites that automatically pull via anacron

Right now, I'm trying to keep the modules in this repository up to date. Typically, I replace the module directory, commit the changes, and push to the repo. Then, all the Drupal sites in our kingdom pull changes. Everyone's up to date, and we all go on with life.

However, I have a module to update that requires update.php to be run. I do not want to chase down upwards of 50 people to get them to run this script. Is there a way to force Drupal to run update.php for me? As part of our policy, we have protections set on update.php so I can't do it through the browser. Ideas?

Comment: No, it would be a terrible security hole if that could just happen. If you need something like that, you'll need to set it up on each client machine first (a git post pull script in everyone's local repo that calls drush updb -y, for example). There are of course many other ways to do it using the OS, but nothing that Drupal can help you with, and nothing that won't involve setting something up on each client machine. Also, what are you planning for contingency? Blindly automating updates on a production site is not a good idea

Comment: @Clive that's what I figured. I'll have to see if I can hammer together a git hook with drush. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yep, the hammer is where it's at! Don't delete this though, you never know, maybe someone's already done all the leg work for this and will be able to provide a nearly-built solution

Comment: re: contingency, we do updates on a dev repo and roll changes over to prod. People smarter than me built this system, and we haven't scorched the earth (yet).